# Limit multisite/network site names to a property of the user

Tags: multisite, directory, customization

We need to limit the blog names users may choose when they create their own blogs.

We have a WordPress Network configured to have all blogs share a domain name. E.g., **domain.name.com/x**, **domain.name.com/y**, etc.

We have integrated our WordPress Network with our corporate Active Directory using the Active Directory Integration plugin. That plugin puts the user's **mailnickname** attribute (the part of the email address before the `@`) into the **nickname** field.

I would like to allow users to self-create their own blogs but restrict blog names names so that it must match the **nickname** field of their WordPress account. E.g., a user with nickname **jdoe** could only create a blog named **domain.name.com/jdoe**.

Ideally, on **/wp-signup.php**, it would be best if the **blogname** field doesn't even display.

Is there a way to do this without PHP customization? I was hoping a plugin would already exist, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source of `wp-signup.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-signup.php), it looks like your best bet might be to filter `signup_blog_init` (line 303 in v. 3.5.1):

```
/*
add_filter( 'signup_blog_init', 'wpse103022_blog_name' );
function wpse103022_blog_name( $blog_details ) {
    // Set $username to the user's username
    $blog_details['blogname'] = $username;
    return $blog_details;
}
*/
// see code below for replacement
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but it's worth a try.

#### Edited

OK, after your comment below, I took a look at `validate_blog_signup()`.  It calls `wpmu_validate_blog_signup()`, and *that* provides a filter -- `wpmu_validate_blog_signup`.  [Looking at the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L620), it appears that something like the following should work:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_validate_blog_signup', 'wpse103039_blog_name' );
function wpse103039_blog_name( $blog_details ) {
    $blog_details['path'] = '/' . $desired_blogname; // however you get it
    return $blog_details;
}
```

If I'm reading the code right, you can filter:

- `domain`
- `path`
- `blogname`
- `blog_title`
- `user`
- `errors`

Comment: Thank you! Our usernames are random 8 digit numbers, so I need to use the user's nickname attribute.

Comment: OK, I'm finally in to this deeply now. It looks like **signup_blog_init** is just for making the signup form, not for processing the signup after the user presses submit. It looks like **validate_blog_signup** is what I'm after here, and it appears to have no hooks. :-( Specifically, looks like I need to replace instances of **$_POST['blogname']** with the value that I need to use instead.

Comment: Updated answer with new info -- hopefully this'll do what you need.

Comment: I appreciate the discovery. I didn't think to look in **ms-functions.php**. Still has no effect. Looking further.

Comment: OK, this is it: `$blog_details['path'] = "/".$desired_blogname;`. Update your answer and I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help out.

Comment: No, it's **path**, not **blogname**. :-)

Comment: Whoops, got it.

Comment: The **wp-signup.php** page will need customization to hide the blogname field.

Comment: That might be fodder for a new question, if you're having trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks. I did get it fixed. There's no hooks where the HTML is spat out, hence the need for manual edits. Just noting that in the comments.